# How do I safely restart TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

It's not obvious to me..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you do kill TSVNCache, you don't need to manually restart it, the shell-extension will do that next time it needs it.

If you're trying to restart the shell-extension, you might achieve it by killing all Explorer.exe processes, and anything else which has ended-up with TSVN in-process.  This is basically any app which has asked the shell about icons, or has used the common file/directory dialogs.   You may need to use something like "Process Explorer" (sysinternals) to find which processes have the TSVN DLLs loaded.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't see the TortoiseSVN icons anymore you can restart `TSVNCache.exe` by navigating to TortoiseSVN's `bin` directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`, and double clicking on it. Note that if you restart it in this way it will be killed when you logout. Otherwise follow the suggestions from the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

The background process that watches your file system for SVN related files and folders is TSVNCache.exe. You can kill that process and start it again, or just reboot your machine :)